# How to Translate innerHTML text in Angular JS controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi i am developing a Angular JS web application with two languages(English and Italy) support. So far i have done all the translations from my html page like below and it works fine.

```
{{translation.ERROR_12}}
```

Now i need to pass some text from controller like below

```
case 'ERROR_12': document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML= "Reporting error 12";
                break;
```

All my translations are stored in .json file. If case matches then i need to display the corresponding message with translations. If i hardcode the innerHTML text like above then in Non english languages also it is showing same text. How can i apply translation for above code ? So that i don't write the description in innerHTML.
My deserved output should something like:

```
case 'ERROR_12': document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML= $translate.ERROR_12;
                break;
```

Comment: case 'ERROR_12':$("#errorDiv).html($translate.ERROR_12); would be better.

Comment: var someVar = $scope.$translate.ERROR_12; case 'ERROR_12':$("#errorDiv).html(someVar );

Comment: Please post a portion of your language in .json file

Comment: @RishiPrakash thanks for your quick reply. i have tried your code, But it doesn't work.

Comment: @WayneEllery {"ERR_001": "Reporting error 1",
"ERR_002": "Reporting error 2",
"ERR_003": "Reporting error 3" }

Comment: @RishiPrakash i am using controller like below app.controller('notiController', function($http, $scope, $timeout) {
$scope.latestnotification = function(){
}
}

If i pass the $translate as a parameter with $scope i am getting errors. Should i pass $translate somewhere else ?

Comment: @radha what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

For HTML Part

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<div ng-click="callMeToSetErrorCode(1)" style="cursor:pointer">Click me to set error code1</div>
    <div ng-click="callMeToSetErrorCode(2)" style="cursor:pointer">Click me to set error code2</div>
    <div ng-click="callMeToSetErrorCode(3)" style="cursor:pointer">Click me to set error code3</div>

<div id="toShowError">
    {{ErrorToshow}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller part : Controller TodoCtrl
function TodoCtrl($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.allStatusInEng = {"ERR_001": "Reporting error 1", "ERR_002": "Reporting error 2", "ERR_003": "Reporting error 3" };
    $scope.allStatusInItalian = {"ERR_001": "Reporting error 1 Italianno", "ERR_002": "Reporting error 2 Italianno", "ERR_003":  "Reporting error 3 Italianno" };

```
alert("Helping Radha----");
$scope.ErrorToshow = "";
//If you know ,in which language in you need to show message you can set it as Default in a variable
    //For example if you are using Italian language

   // $scope.nameOfActivejson = "allStatusInItalian";
 $rootScope.nameOfActivejson = "allStatusInItalian";
$scope.callMeToSetErrorCode = function(){

    $scope.currentErrorCode = "ERR_001";
    $scope.callSwitchCase($scope.currentErrorCode);

  }
$scope.callMeToRevertLang = function(){
    $rootScope.nameOfActivejson ="allStatusInEng";
    alert("Ok done" +$rootScope.nameOfActivejson);

}
$scope.callSwitchCase = function(presentError){
    alert($rootScope.nameOfActivejson);
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope[$rootScope.nameOfActivejson]));
  switch (presentError) {
case 'ERR_001':
     $scope.ErrorToshow = $scope[$rootScope.nameOfActivejson]['ERR_001'];
    break;
case 'ERR_002':
   $scope.ErrorToshow = $scope[$rootScope.nameOfActivejson]['ERR_002'];
    break;
case 'ERR_003':
    $scope.ErrorToshow = $scope[$rootScope.nameOfActivejson]['ERR_003'];
    break;
```

}}

}

Comment: If i do like that, where can write italian translations ?

Comment: Yes, i am maintaining two json files for two languages with same key

Comment: I Should not hardcode the translations in my code. Because client may change error descriptions in future. So i have to access the keys from json file only. I need solution in more Angular way with using some directives like $filter, $translate etc..

Comment: @radha You can store error descriptions in database, and on page load can create JSONs from those values.